# Angular 9 ContentChildren element is undefined within foreach loop

Tags: angular, typescript, components, undefined-behavior, angular9

My Parent Component has the following children

```
<app-table>
<div class="abc" #abc>
    <h2>Date</h2>
    <app-date></app-date>
</div>
<app-date></app-date>
<app-date></app-date>
</app-table>
```

My Table component has

```
<ng-content select=".abc"></ng-content>
...
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

In My app-table.ts component I have:

```
@ContentChildren(DateComponent, {read: DateComponent, descendants:true }) datechildren:QueryList<DateComponent>
...
ngAfterContentInit() {
console.log(this.datechildren.toArray().forEach((element)=>element.realdate));//this returns undefined
}
```

Finally, my app-date ts has

```
...
realdate: Date = new Date ();
  intervalID:any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(this.intervalID=() => {
      this.realdate = new Date();
   }, 100);
  }
```

When I try `console.log(this.datechildren.toArray())`, I can see the array, but as soon as I loop in to the element properties, I get undefined.

I have tried

```
this.datechildren.changes.subscribe((changes: any) => console.log(this.datechildren.toArray().forEach((element)=>element.realdate)));
```

Tried with and without `{read: DateComponent, descendants:true }`.
I also tried deleting the abc class ng content, leaving only one ng content, still doesnt work.
I have also tried calling other properties, even a simple string, it is still undefined.

Please help with retrieving the realdate or other properties.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly msitake, actually.
Instead of 
console.log(this.datechildren.toArray().forEach((element)=>element.realdate));//this returns undefined
I had to write
this.datechildren.toArray().forEach((element)=>console.log(element.realdate));